# How to Insert an external jsp in GWT whithout using iframe

Tags: jsp, dom, gwt, iframe, insert

i want to insert an external jsp in our gwt app. With the frame widget from GWT that is possible, but this is not exactly, what i'm looking for. The problem is, that with iframe i have more than one DOM...but i wish to have exactly one DOM. Any suggestion, how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch the inner page's HTML (using [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html)) and call [`setInnerHTML()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#setInnerHTML%28java.lang.String%29) on some element in your DOM.

This is pretty risky, and you'll need to really fully vet the HTML that you're setting in there, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL `<c:import>` to import external resources. You only need to take care that the final HTML is [valid](http://validator.w3.org) and you thus don't end up with nested `<html>` tags or so.